# pyOSC simple Server

Tags: python, osc, max-msp-jitter

I'm working on a simple program where Max-msp send some integers via OSC to python. I'm using the pyOSC library for python.
Now i can easily print the numbers but i can't decode it and use it as an integer inside python (i'm noob).

ideas?

```
import OSC
import time, threading

receive_address = '127.0.0.1', 9000

def printing_handler(addr, tags, stuff, source):
    print "---"
    print "received new osc msg from %s" % OSC.getUrlStr(source)
    print "with addr : %s" % addr
    print "typetags %s" % tags
    print "data %s" % stuff
    print "---"

s = OSC.OSCServer(receive_address) 
s.addMsgHandler("/numero", printing_handler) 

st = threading.Thread( target = s.serve_forever )
st.start()
```

thank you very much !

Comment: Can't decode *what*? `int(stuff)` doesn't work?

Comment: just taking the data number and transform it to an integer to use inside my program

Comment: Sure, and `int()` casting doesn't work? What are the errors when you try?

Comment: just int(stuff) is :"int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'"

Comment: int(stuff[0]) : Message-callback <function printing_handler at 0x1004f6848> did not return OSCMessage or None: <type 'int'>
---

Comment: Well, `stuff` is a rather non-descriptive name and I don't know what type that actually is. If it's a list, I don't know what types are inside

Comment: stuff it's a list. it's a OSC message with data

Comment: Okay, well, assuming there are strings in the list `int(stuff[0])` is correct. Can you `print type(stuff[0])`?

Comment: yes : "<type 'int'>"

Comment: Alright, then there you go. No need to have `int(stuff[0])` just `print "data %d" % stuff[0]` should be fine

Comment: but then if i want to return just the integer: stuff [0] ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what all the types / length of `stuff` is, but, for example if `type(stuff[0])` is already `<type 'int'>`, then you can simply use that value as-is.

Comment: but then if i want to assign stuff[0] to a variable?

Comment: If you want the integer, then yes

Comment: but then if i return the values i get: "  <function printing_handler at 0x1005f6848> did not return OSCMessage or None: <type 'int'>

Comment: Why are you trying to return anything?

Comment: i need that integer for using it inside my python program

Comment: You can't `return` that integer from `printing_handler`, though. That's what the error is telling you. You can *use the integer* fine

Answer (score 0):

`stuff` is the OSC message's arguments. You should be able to retrieve them directly. Let's say you're sending 3 ints from Max, you should be able to do something like this:

```
def printing_handler(addr, tags, stuff, source):
    print "---"
    arg1 = stuff[0]
    arg2 = stuff[1]
    arg3 = stuff[2]
    print "received",arg1,arg2,arg3
    print "---"
```

If it helps, you can try playing with the pyOSC example code:

- Max5 [OSCTester.maxpat](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptone/pyosc/master/Max5/OSCTester.maxpat)
- [knect-rcv.py](https://github.com/ptone/pyosc/blob/master/examples/knect-rcv.py)

Comment: thank you, the problem is that if i try to return arg1 for example i get the error: Message-callback <function printing_handler at 0x102830500> did not return OSCMessage or None: <type 'int'>

Comment: strange, I've just tested with the snippet above with 3 numbers sent from max and it worked. is there anything else in your script ?

Comment: yes the code above works really well, the problem is that i would like to export arg1 for example and use it outside the script

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear how you are planning to export arg1 and use it outside the script. Could you please clarify ? If you want to use arg1 outside the callback function, create arg1 outside the scope function, but remember to use the `global arg1` inside the callback if you are not using a class (e.g. `self`)